# What causes JavaFX 2.0 to re-draw the GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx-2

I'm just starting with JavaFX and I am having a hard time with some of the transitioning from Swing: When I write in Swing I can re-draw the GUI by calling `repaint()` but I can't figure out how to do this in JavaFX?

I have a `BorderPane` that I swap a different HBox into in response to a user action. When I debug this and follow what it does, it looks like it's doing exactly what I asked: The new HBox is created and added to the `BorderPane` via `setBottom()` but after the method returns I still get the original box in the pane. IE, the GUI was not re-drawn. I'm sure this is something elementary but it's frustrating. :)

Example:

```
public class MainFrameNode extends BorderPane{

MessageVBox messageBox = new MessageVBox();
ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();

public MainFrameNode(){
    setPrefSize(600, 700);
    setBottom(new ButtonsHBox());

    sp.setContent(messageBox);
    sp.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    sp.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
    setCenter(sp);
}

    public void setBottomBox(Node box){
        //AgentTester.getRoot().getChildren().remove(0);
        setBottom(box);
        //AgentTester.getRoot().getChildren().add(this);//AgentTester.getMainFrame());
}
```

In this example I have a BorderPane that has a HBox in it's bottom pane. I want to swap the HBox for a different HBox, and have the gui redraw. I can use the two commented-out lines to remove and re-add the whole broder pane (Though that, apperently, has its own problems) but if I just use setBottom() the gui does not re-draw. Hope this helps clearify my question.

The code to use MainFrameNode is also very basic:

```
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {

    final MainFrameNode mainFrame = new MainFrameNode();
    instantiateClient(mainFrame.getMessageBox());
    root.getChildren().add(mainFrame);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    arg0.setScene(scene);   
    arg0.setOnHiding(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>(){
        public void handle(WindowEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    arg0.show();
}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal code example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: your code looks correct, can you also provide code there you use `MainFrameNode`?

Comment: Added the code for using MainFrameNode, as requested

Comment: but u never call setBottomBox() in your code...